# Overwrite elements at end of priority queue once specified capacity is met?

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue, nearest-neighbor

I'm trying to search for the nearest N points in a quad tree and using an STL priority queue to store the points as they are found (sorted by distance from the query point).

Points exceeding a max distance from the query point are never added to the queue.  However, I also would like to cut off the number of items that can be returned by the search.  Currently, I add all points which are closer to the query point than the max distance, and then only read the top N points from the queue.

In testing, this is too slow -- simply adding every point closer than the max distance ends up slowing down as more points are added.  I would instead like to only add more points to the queue if either: there are fewer than N points currently in the queue, or the point in question is closer to the query point than the Nth point in the queue, in which case that point is overriden, and does not increase the number of elements in the queue.

Is there a way to do this with the STL priority queue, or is my only option to write my own?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to know the current N best points while you iterate through them?  If not, perhaps you can add all the points to a random-access container (e.g. `std::vector`)and just call [`std::partial_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort) at the end to get the N best.

If you really need to do it with a priority queue, `std::priority_queue` won't suffice.  You could put something together with the `std::algorithm` heap functions, which lets you access the underlying container.